# Bootstrap 3 - Form Input Element Alignment Fixing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a form and have done this-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Disposed In Landfill - Tons</span>
        <input required type="text" name="disposed_in_landfill_tons" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Sold Tons</span>
        <input required type="text" name="sold_tons" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Sold - Net Cash</span>
        <input required type="text" name="sold_net_cash" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Recycled - Tons</span>
        <input required type="text" name="recycled_tons" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Recycled - Net Cash</span>
        <input required type="text" name="recycled_net_cash" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Reused - Tons</span>
        <input required type="text" name="reused_tons" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Reuse - Saved</span>
        <input required type="text" name="reuse_saved" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Donation - Tons</span>
        <input required type="text" name="donation_tons" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Donation - Value</span>
        <input required type="text" name="donation_value" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Total Cost to Dispose</span>
        <input required type="text" name="total_cost_to_dipose" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Actual Cost Dispose</span>
        <input required type="text" name="actual_cost" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Disposal Avoidance Saving</span>
        <input required type="text" name="disposal_avoidance_savings" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

And find a output like this-

[image]

So, the problem is I want to make the left side all boxes to same alignment.

(Like all in the red colored line)

Can anyoun help me please?

> Edit

I have tried -

```
width:300px;
text-align: right;
```

But not fixing

Comment: Do you want it to be of some fixed width, or all of them to be of the same width as the widest label? Because latter is not quite possible with CSS only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to have fixed width, set `min-width` to the `input-group-addon`. This will let them align equally.

`width` did not work for you because it is already overridden by `width: 1%` coming from Bootstrap code. If you overwrite it with proper CSS priority order, it will work as well.

```css
.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Disposed In Landfill - Tons</span>
    <input required type="text" name="disposed_in_landfill_tons" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Sold Tons</span>
    <input required type="text" name="sold_tons" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Sold - Net Cash</span>
    <input required type="text" name="sold_net_cash" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Recycled - Tons</span>
    <input required type="text" name="recycled_tons" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Recycled - Net Cash</span>
    <input required type="text" name="recycled_net_cash" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Reused - Tons</span>
    <input required type="text" name="reused_tons" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Reuse - Saved</span>
    <input required type="text" name="reuse_saved" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Donation - Tons</span>
    <input required type="text" name="donation_tons" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Donation - Value</span>
    <input required type="text" name="donation_value" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Total Cost to Dispose</span>
    <input required type="text" name="total_cost_to_dipose" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Actual Cost Dispose</span>
    <input required type="text" name="actual_cost" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Disposal Avoidance Saving</span>
    <input required type="text" name="disposal_avoidance_savings" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```